# How can TextView be aligned right next to an ImageButton in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I am trying to have a `TextView` right next to an `ImageButton`. However, the `TextView` isn't aligned well. I want it to start at the same top position as the `ImageButton`.

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytexview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#DF533B"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use ImageView instead of ImageButton becz ImageButton set image over button so image is not cover whole area so try to use ImageView which cover whole space which is allocated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` for both `ImageButton` and `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytexview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textColor="#DF533B"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or Use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"` and add `android:gravity="center"` for that `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytexview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textColor="#DF533B"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set this property to view element `android:gravity="top"` inside the `TextView` tag.

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytexview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/myimage"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#DF533B"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do android:layout_height="match_parent" and set gravity center .

use below code:-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytexview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#DF533B"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

`android:gravity="top"` in textview